# Video recording using external microphone and smartphone

Tags: video, audio-recording, microphone, software, audio

My plan is to record gameplay (using fraps) and myself using a Galaxy S + microphone. I then want to glue them together into one video - picture in picture kind of thing.

My concern is for the part where I use my phone (filming myself): do I have to put the audio and video together in an editing software? Or is the phone smart enough to match the sound that the external mic captures with the image?

Thanks a lot in advance. Also, feel free to recommend a good (~40$) microphone.

Cheers,

Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the microphone is hooked in to the phone, then it should be an input to the camera app and it should record both at the same time.  If the microphone was not linked to the camera app for some reason but was recording separately, it isn't that hard to sync, just clap on camera and look for the spike on the waveform and align it with the clap.  I wouldn't expect it to be a problem though.